# Word by word palindrome program

Tags: c++, queue, stack

So T've found a million examples of palindrome programs that check for a single word palindrome.

But T need help doing one word by word for example the sentence You can cage a swallow cant you but you cant swallow a cage can you?" would be a word by word palindrome. I just need a jump start the example code the book gave is this

```
// FILE: pal.cxx
// Program to test whether an input line is a palindrome. Spaces,
// punctuation, and the difference between upper- and lowercase are ignored.

#include <cassert>    // Provides assert
#include <cctype>     // Provides isalpha, toupper
#include <cstdlib>    // Provides EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <iostream>   // Provides cout, cin, peek
#include <queue>      // Provides the queue template class
#include <stack>      // Provides the stack template class
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
queue<char> q;
stack<char> s;
char letter;            
queue<char>::size_type mismatches = 0;  // Mismatches between queue and stack
cout << "Enter a line and I will see if it's a palindrome:" << endl;

while (cin.peek( ) != '\n')
{
    cin >> letter;
    if (isalpha(letter))
    {
        q.push(toupper(letter));
        s.push(toupper(letter));
    }
}

while ((!q.empty( )) && (!s.empty( )))
{
    if (q.front( ) != s.top( ))
        ++mismatches;
    q.pop( );
    s.pop( );
}

if (mismatches == 0)
    cout << "That is a palindrome." << endl;
else
    cout << "That is not a palindrome." << endl;    
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: Isn't that already a jump start?

Comment: hmm..what's the question?

Comment: @Asha i need to know how to do a word by word palindrome, the only thing i can think of is using strings but i dont know how to pop out a string piece by piece

Comment: @kylestrand yeah i guess it is ha

Comment: If you want help extracting a string, then that should be your question. Right now, your question does not clearly state what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do from your base code actually. You just need to add words (strings) to your queue and stack instead of chars. I quickly modified the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
queue<std::string> q;
stack<std::string> s;
std::string word;
queue<std::string>::size_type mismatches = 0;  // Mismatches between queue and stack
cout << "Enter a line and I will see if it's a palindrome:" << endl;

while (cin.peek( ) != '\n')
{
    cin >> word;
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::toupper);
    q.push(word);
    s.push(word);
}
```

By reading in a string with cin, you're automatically using white space as a delimiter. The line:

```
std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(),word.begin(), ::toupper);
```

converts all characters in the string to uppercase.

Comment: Thanks i knew it was simple i just was missing a simple step. Thanks!